# Syntax Error: Token Join at Position 760 when importing SQL into Discoverer 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql, token

I wrote the query (below) in PL/SQL Developer for a client and would like to import it into Oracle Discoverer Desktop 11g so the report is self-serve. The query works perfectly in PL/SQL but when I go to import it into Discoverer, I get the following errors: "Error: Syntax error: token JOIN at position 760. Error: Parse stopped due to fatal errors."

Can anyone tell me what these errors mean and how to resolve the issue?

Thanks!

Query:

```
Select eid.person_code, eid.last_name plnownr_lname, eid.first_name plnownr_fname, eid.birth_date plnownr_DOB, des.status_code, dun.unit_code, ect.last_name BenRecip_LNAME, ect.first_name BenRecip_fname, ect.birth_date BenRecip_DOB,decode(ect.relation,'00','Unknown','01','Spouse','02','Common-Law Spouse','03','Partner', '05','Daughter','06','Son','07','Step-Daughter','08','Step-Son','09', 'Granddaughter','11', 'Father','12','Mother', '20','Sister','21','Brother','24','Aunt','28','Nephew','29','Ex-spouse','31','Friend','43','Trust','50','User Defined','52','User Defined', '53','User Defined','54','User Defined',ect.relation) relation, bpn.description, bpn.plan_code, bend.premium_start_date, bend.premium_end_date

From p2k_hr_identities eid
Join p2k_hr_contacts ect on ect.eid_id = eid.id
Join p2k_be_benefit_recipients bbr on bbr.ect_id = ect.id
Join p2k_be_enrollments ben on ben.id = bbr.ben_id
Join p2k_be_plan_definitions bpn on bpn.id = ben.bpn_id
Join p2k_hr_employments eem on eem.eid_id = eid.id
     and eem.termination_date is null
Join p2k_hr_assignments eas on eas.eem_id = eem.id
Join p2k_hr_assignment_details easd on easd.eas_id = eas.id 
     and easd.expiry = to_date('3999-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
Join p2k_cm_units dun on dun.id = easd.dun_id
Join p2k_be_enrollment_details bend on bend.ben_id = ben.id 
     and bend.premium_end_date = to_date('3999-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd') 
     and bend.premium_start_date != to_date('0001-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
Join p2k_cm_employment_statuses des on des.id = easd.des_id
     and des.status_code not in ('TERMINATED', 'RETIRED')

Union

Select eid.person_code, eid.last_name plnownr_lname, eid.first_name eplnownr_fname, eid.birth_date plnownr_dob, des.status_code, dun.unit_code, eid.last_name BenRecip_lname, eid.first_name BenRecip_fname, eid.birth_date BenRecip_dob, 'Employee-NoRelation', bpn.description, bpn.plan_code, bend.premium_start_date, bend.premium_end_date

From p2k_hr_identities eid
Join p2k_hr_employments eem on eem.eid_id = eid.id
     and eem.termination_date is null
Join p2k_be_enrollments ben on ben.eem_id = eem.id
Join p2k_be_plan_definitions bpn on bpn.id = ben.bpn_id
Join p2k_hr_assignments eas on eas.eem_id = eem.id
Join p2k_hr_assignment_details easd on easd.eas_id = eas.id 
     and easd.expiry = to_date('3999-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
Join p2k_cm_units dun on dun.id = easd.dun_id
Join p2k_be_enrollment_details bend on bend.ben_id = ben.id 
     and bend.premium_end_date = to_date('3999-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd') 
     and bend.premium_start_date != to_date('0001-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
Join p2k_cm_employment_statuses des on des.id = easd.des_id
     and des.status_code not in ('TERMINATED', 'RETIRED')
Order by 2,3,5,6
```

Comment: Not something I'm familiar with, but might you be hitting [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/b40106/advance.htm#sthref1579)? Not a helpful error message if so...

Comment: I have followed these steps but once I select the file to open (step 2) I get the error as above.

Comment: Hmm, the links are jumping around... I was referring to the note: 'If you are importing an SQL script tha contains join definitions, the joins must have been created first by your Discoverer manager using Discoverer Administrator.' Have tou created the joins? I have no real idea what that means, I'm just guessing *8-)

Comment: Try changing `Join` to `Inner Join`.  Just thinkin'...  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Interesting, @BobJarvis - when I changed the joins to inner joins, I still got a token error, but a slightly different flavor:     Error: Syntax error: token INNER at position 761.
Error: Parse stopped due to fatal errors.